# What is the best data structure for storing a fixed length collection of named constants that can be used in a switch without explicit casting?

Tags: c++, containers

What is the best data structure for storing a fixed length collection of named constants that can be used in a switch without explicit casting?

I want to write clean code that looks like this:

```
   enum class EventType : uint8_t{
      NOTE_ON = 9,
      NOTE_OFF = 8,
      CONTROL_CHANGE = 11,
      CHANNEL_PRESSURE = 13,
      PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE = 14
   };

   // Sometime later in a function scope:
   using enum EventType;
   switch(((Status & 0xF0)>>4)){
         case NOTE_OFF:
            std::cout << "NOTE OFF: " << std::endl;
         break;
         case NOTE_ON:
            std::cout << "NOTE ON: " std::endl;
         break;
         case CONTROL_CHANGE:
            std::cout << "CONTROL CHANGE: " <<std::endl;           
         break;
         case CHANNEL_PRESSURE: 
            std::cout << "CHANNEL PRESSURE: " <<std::endl;
         break;
         case PITCH_WHEEL_CHANGE:
            std::cout << "PITCH WHEEL CHANGE: " << std::endl;
         break;
         default:
            std::cout << "UNKNOWN EVENT TYPE: " << <<std::endl;
   }
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to use an `enum class` in a `switch` without explicitly casting the value to an `int` in every single `case` statement which is very verbose and defeats the point of using clean, easy to read labels.

Is there a better data container choice for this?

Criteria:

- The number and length of items in the container is fixed and known at compile time.
- The contents will never change at run time.
- The text labels do not need to be displayed or printed out.
- Data should be in some type of collection to avoid namespace pollution.
- The goal is to have a set of human-readable labels on `switch` cases, `if`, etc.
- The labels should be usable with the least verbosity possible to keep the code clean. ie. no need to explicitly cast it or call a member function to extract something.

Comment: Use a normal non-class `enum`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The problem with that is you can't reuse the labels inside the `enum` anywhere else in your class or in another non-class `enum`.

Comment: Not having worked with enum classes, I wonder if you can't just convert the value given to `switch` once. That said, you can still wrap the old-style enum into a class to prevent pollution of the surrounding namespace: `struct Event { enum Type { type_note_on, type_note_off};};` and then refer to the elements using `Event::type_note_on` etc.

Comment: Will that really be a problem? Especially for something as specific as MIDI events (which it looks like)? Otherwise, just do the cast, and add a comment about why the cast is needed.

Comment: Well, either you use a non-class enum, or you have to cast in the switch statement (or cast the labels :( ). Why do you need it to work without the cast?

Comment: Use an `int` operand, use an `enum class` operand, avoid casts: pick two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the **condition** for the `switch` to the enumeration type:

```
switch(static_cast<EventType>((Status & 0xF0)>>4)) {…}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define an accessor for the event part of the status (and do this for the other parts as well):

```
EventType event(int status) 
{ 
    return static_cast<EventType>((status & 0xF0) >> 4); 
}
```

and then

```
switch(event(Status)){
     case EventType::NOTE_OFF:
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define shift and bitwise operators for your `enum class`:

```
inline EventType operator&(EventType a, std::uint8_t b)
    { return EventType(std::uint8_t(a) & b); }

inline EventType operator>>(EventType a, std::uint8_t s)
    { return EventType(std::uint8_t(a) >> s); }
```